# Is it possible to align absolute-positioned elements below eachother?

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```
<div class="member">
    <div class="memberImage"><img src="" /></div>
    <div class="memberInfo">John Doe</div>
</div>
```

This is the css for it:

```
.member {
    width:200px;
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;
    padding:5px;
}
```

When I duplicate this div just beneath this one they appear to be one over the other because of the `position:absolute`.

Is it possible to keep the `position:absolute` and have them one below the other as normal?

Thanks,

Comment: Since `absolute` means position relative to the parent, you can set element's position with the `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` properties.

Comment: `clear` is used for floated element, therefore, useless here. Can you explain why you need this div to be in absolute position? Why not floated or relative?

Comment: I don't need it to be in absolute position, but I was very interested to know if it can be done while it is in absolute position.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to keep the
>   position:absolute and have them one
>   below the other as normal?

**Simple answer: *no*.**

**Possible solutions:**

- Add a `top` attribute to the member class and increment for every member
- Don't use absolute positioning (probably wisest in this case)

Judging from your code snippet you want to create a memberlist. A simple pattern that would fit well for this is simply an `UL` (Unordered list):

```
<ul class="memberlist">
    <li>
        <div class="memberImage"><img src="foo.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="memberInfo">John Doe</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="memberImage"><img src="foo.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="memberInfo">John Doe</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="memberImage"><img src="foo.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="memberInfo">John Doe</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And a corresponding CSS to go with it:

```
.memberlist li {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to keep the `position:absolute` and have them one below the other as normal?

Well, uh, no, because `position:absolute` is designed to allow you to specify an absolute position for an element.

This means that it will default to the top-left corner of the element that it is absolutely positioned against, and can be positioned according to your requirements using `top` and `left` attributes (or `bottom` and `right` if you prefer).

You could specify the two elements to have specific `top` positioning so that they could appear one below the other, which would answer your question, but really what you're asking for isn't absolute positioning, so `position:absolute` is inappropriate.

You you probably want instead is `position:relative`, which works more like a normally positioned element, except that you can override it using `top` and `left`, etc. This would allow you to do what you want, so it sounds like the answer to your question.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have used class names, hence same style to both, so both have absolute position, you can either give them ids or use position: relative